# What are the available ways to pass a parameter to a UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, parameter-passing

What are the available ways to pass a parameter to a `UserControl` ?

I know the session option but actually I don't prefer it because it'll retain when any exception is occurred. I mean I prefer something like the QueryString (rely on the call or request).

Note: My `UserControl` will be shown throught a modal popup using JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a public property on the UserControl, then set that property's value on the page the UserControl lives.  Since UserControl events occur before the page's events (except for the Page_Load event - the page's Load starts before the UserControl, set the value of the property in your Page_Load (or earlier) event.